ROS2 bag record: Serialization format?
the CLI for ros2 bag record offers the option --serialization-format:

The rmw serialization format in which the messages are saved, defaults
to the rmw currently in use.

Can someone explain the different formats to me?
Looking at the ros2bag Python API, the method rosbag2_py.get_registered_serializers() is called. This returns an empty set in my case (Ubuntu 24.04, jazzy). So which serialization format is used and which are available?
